# PHP Ajax Submit Form Return Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following form in my HTML page:

```
        <form id="submission" action="testresponse.php" method="post">
            <input id="URL" name="URL" type="text">
            <button name="Submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

`testresponse.php` just contains `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` to print all the post variables.

I am trying to submit the form and have it return the values on the same page that the page was submitted (i.e. return the POST variables somewhere above the form)

I used the following jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var frm = $('#submission');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.responseText);
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

But for some reason `data.responseText` always returns blank

Is there a way to have my form send a POST request to a PHP page and return the result?

Comment: simply do with `console.log(data)`

Comment: @DaveChen `type: frm.attr('method'),` is right syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change from

```
console.log(data.responseText)
```

to

```
console.log(data)
```